# Lose classes in VS C++ 6.0 when backing up project

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a project that contains 235+ source and header files.  In my standard development cycle, I develop a little, test that development, create a release version, test that and deliver that release to my customer.  I then copy the project directory and change its name.  I then start all over again to address new customer requirements.

This iteration however something terminal happened.  After copying the directory into a newly made directory, I brought it into the MSC++ 6.0 development environment I normally use.  To my surprise only 15 of the more than 140 classes are now being displayed in the ClassView tab of the Workspace window.  All the files are there in the FileView tab.  The project totally compiles and links and executes correctly.

I have deleted the *.clw in the directory and rebuilt it via the ClassWizard, but get the same results as above.

Can anyone point out what I did that prevents me from backing up my project the way I outline above?  (I can still go back to the original project files and they work fine.)

Comment: I would recommend the use of a version control system. It will make your life much easier!

Comment: +1000 for source control - subversion/git/mercurial are free - learn them use them, life will get easier

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for all your responses.

I found that if I exited MS C++, then deleted the *.clw and the *.ncb files, then brought up C++ and used the ClassWizard to rebuild its database, everything returned to normal.

Answer (score 0):

A solution by Microsoft iw there: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/294704. You can first close all projects usicg File -> Close Workspace. Moreover verify that all headers and related sources are in FileView pane. I hope this will work.